# Samsung galaxy s3 not rebooting in recovery mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My galaxy s3 will not reboot after I've wiped cache and did factory reset.  The little guy just says error and it shuts off.

Comment: Can you please specify, where the error appears?

Answer (score -1):

You should reflash the recovery

Comment: 1) Why and 2) how should the recovery being flashed again? What should be gained by that? Obviously, recovery is working if OP was able to "wipe cache".